# How to find the same values next to each other in multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I tried to write a function that would find in a multidimensional array (with values from 3 to 7) repeating values for at least 3 times next to each other (vertical and horizontal). And if it finds that, change it for a different value. Let's say 1.

I tried to do this by loops but it doesn't seem to be a good way to solve that or I messed it up. Because for some array it works, for some it does not.

Here's my code:

```js
function searching(array) {
  for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    let horizontal = array[i][0];
    let howMany = 1;

    for (j = 1; j < array[i].length; j++) {
      if (horizontal === array[i][j]) {
        howMany += 1;
        horizontal = array[i][j];
        if (howMany >= 3) {
          for (d = j; d > j - howMany; d--) {
            array[i][d] = 0;
          }
        }
      } else {
        horizontal = array[i][j];
        howMany = 1;
      }

    }

  }


  for (v = 0; v < array.length; v++) {
    let vertical = array[0][v];
    let howMany = 1;
    for (x = 1; x < array.length; x++) {
      if (vertical === array[x][v]) {
        howMany++;
        vertical = array[x][v];
        if (howMany >= 3) {
          for (d = x; d > x - howMany; d--) {
            array[d][v] = 0;
          }
        }
      } else {
        vertical = array[x][v];
        howMany = 1;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The idea is to for example give array:

```js
let array = [
    [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    [3, 4, 5, 5, 5],
    [3, 5, 6, 7, 4]
  ]
```

And the result should be:

```js
let result = [
    [1, 1, 1, 6, 7],
    [1, 1, 1, 6, 7],
    [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    [1, 5, 6, 7, 4]
  ]
```

Thanks in advance for any ideas how to solve it :) Greetings!

Comment: 6 is present 3 times, why is not set to 1 ?

Comment: Because it is not next to another value 6 that repeats next to each other at least for 3 times.

Comment: You say "for some [arrays] it does not [work]". Could you elaborate on those edge cases? For example, is the edge case you have a problem with the cases where a vertical and horizontal sequence of the same value intersect? If so, then the cause is that you're overwriting values before they can be used to calculate additional sequences. You can resolve that edge case by copying your multidimensional array, then using the copy for calculations and the original for overwriting values.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand the question at first...
So this is my code:

```js
let array = [
  [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
  [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
  [3, 4, 5, 5, 5],
  [3, 5, 6, 7, 4]
];

function replace(arr, target = 1) {
  let needToChange = []; // save the index to change
  const numbers = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
  const m = arr.length; // m rows
  const n = arr[0].length; // n columns

  let mi = 0;
  let ni = 0;

  // search in row
  for (mi = 0; mi < m; mi++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++) {
      const num = numbers[x]; // number to search
      let counter = 0; // counter for this number in row mi
      let tempArr = [];
      for (ni = 0; ni < n; ni++) {
        const currentNum = arr[mi][ni];
        if (currentNum === num) {
          counter++;
          tempArr.push([mi, ni]);
        }
      }
      if (counter >= 3) {
        needToChange = needToChange.concat(tempArr);
      }
    }
  }

  // search in column
  for (ni = 0; ni < n; ni++) {
    for (let x = 0; x < numbers.length; x++) {
      const num = numbers[x]; // number to search
      let counter = 0; // counter for this number in row mi
      let tempArr = [];
      for (mi = 0; mi < m; mi++) {
        const currentNum = arr[mi][ni];
        if (currentNum === num) {
          counter++;
          tempArr.push([mi, ni]);
        }
      }
      if (counter >= 3) {
        needToChange = needToChange.concat(tempArr);
      }
    }
  }

  // replace
  needToChange.forEach(([i, j]) => {
    array[i][j] = target;
  });
}

replace(array);
array.forEach(row => {
  console.log(row.join(', '));
})
```

Comment: Your output is incorrect - press "Run code snippet"

Comment: It was @Silarsf who asked the question, not me

Answer (score 0):

The problems with your current code are

(1) You're only checking individual rows and columns, when you need to be checking them both (eg, with `[[2, 2], [2, 5]]`, when at the starting position `[0][0]`, you need to look at both `[0][1]` (and its neighbors, if matching) as well as `[1][0]` (and its neighbors, if matching).

(2) You're not actually checking for adjacency at the moment, you're just counting up the total number of matching elements in a particular row or column.

Iterate over all indicies of the array. If an index has already been checked, return early. Recursively search for neighbors to that index, and if at least 3 matching in total are found, set them all to 1. Put all matching neighbors in the `checked` set to avoid checking them again (even if there were less than 2 adjacent matches found total).

```js
setAllAdjacentToOne([
  [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
  [3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
  [3, 4, 5, 5, 5],
  [3, 5, 6, 7, 4]
]);
// all 9s stay, the rest get set to 1:
setAllAdjacentToOne([
  [2, 2, 9, 7, 7],
  [2, 9, 9, 9, 7],
  [3, 4, 4, 5, 5],
  [9, 4, 5, 5, 9]
]);


function setAllAdjacentToOne(input) {
  const output = input.map(subarr => subarr.slice());
  const checked = new Set();
  const getKey = (x, y) => `${x}_${y}`;

  const width = input[0].length;
  const height = input.length;
  const getAllAdjacent = (x, y, numToFind, matches = []) => {
    if (x >= width || x < 0 || y >= height || y < 0) {
      return matches;
    }
    const key = getKey(x, y);
    if (!checked.has(key) && input[y][x] === numToFind) {
      checked.add(key);
      matches.push({ x, y });
      getAllAdjacent(x + 1, y, numToFind, matches);
      getAllAdjacent(x - 1, y, numToFind, matches);
      getAllAdjacent(x, y + 1, numToFind, matches);
      getAllAdjacent(x, y - 1, numToFind, matches);
    }
    return matches;
  };

  output.forEach((innerRowArr, y) => {
    innerRowArr.forEach((num, x) => {
      const allAdjacent = getAllAdjacent(x, y, num);
      if (allAdjacent.length <= 2) {
        return;
      }
      allAdjacent.forEach(({ x, y }) => {
        output[y][x] = 1;
      });
    });
  });
  console.log(JSON.stringify(output));
}
```